# How to know button on/off clicked or not

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I am writing automation for android app.

To write an automation code, I am inspecting an app using uiautomatorviewer(android sdk tools)

I want to view the weather in Fahrenheit and Celsius.

There is a button switch weather units.

After switching weather units, how can i know am in Fahrenheit or Celsius

Here are the screen shot attached

1. Weather units [image]
2. Fahrenheit [image]
3. Celsius [image]

FYI I am not a developer to change Mobile App code. I am writing automation test for Mobile App. Is there any way to automate this using http://appium.io/ with java?

Comment: Use booleans for textview click or I suggest you should use toggle button instead of textviews.

Comment: why aren't you using switch or toggle instead of textview?

Answer (score 0):

use a switch,

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="deg celcius"
    android:textOff="deg fah"/>
```

you've switch on = deg Celcius and  switch off = deg Fahrenheit, so use setOnCheckedChangeListener

```
Switch switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus);
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     boolean isChecked) { 

       if(isChecked){ // deg celcius
           // Do operation
       }else{ // deg fahrenheit
           // Do operation
       }     
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation it looks like you need a ToggleButton[Toggle Button Developer Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).

You can get if the button is checked or not by:

```
boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
```

Once you have togglebutton, in your layout simply set:

```
 android:textOn="@string/Fahrenheit"
 android:textOff="@string/Celsius"
```

OnClickListener of this button perform your respective logic.This should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    YourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
    switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
    }else{
    switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for Switch but still if you want to go for it, then you will have to manage the state(enable/disable) of both textviews by yourself.

```
TextView fehreniteTextview, celsiusTextView;
fehreniteTextview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fehrenite);
celsiusTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.celsius);
```

So here, onClick you will have to change the state of another textview too, like:

```
public void onClickOfFahrenite(View v){
    celsiusTextView.setEnabled(true);
    fehreniteTextview.setEnabled(false);
}

public void onClickOfCelsius(View v){
    celsiusTextView.setEnabled(false);
    fehreniteTextview.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Now before making any decision, you will have to check, which one textview is enabled, using:

```
if(fehreniteTextview.isEnabled())
{
// Do your stuff
}
else
{
// Do your stuff
}
```

I hope, it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the screenshots,background color of textview is changing from grey to blue. So, if you get the background color of textview, it will be possible for you to know which switch is ON.
You can look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/buToEAIDn2c.

Comment: How can i get background color using appium for an app. Refer https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/1920

Answer (score 0):

Every answer here is from Android Developers not Android Testers and none answer your question (they don't seem to have read you can't change the app itself).

The way the app is done you can't do it. UiAutomator doesn't read colours nor stuff like that. So if there is no difference in the properties of those elements (apart from Text and Bounds) it has no way of knowing what selected means.

If the app was correctly done it would be a ToogleButton and then the properties (checked or selected I'm sure which) would indicate which was selected.